# Cloning a csv file to memory and using it in a datatable? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, datatable, clone

I have a question about the following code. in order to prevent problems caused by file locking I came across the following code.

```
            Dim OrignalBitmap As New Bitmap(Application.StartupPath & "\IMAGES\BACKGROUND_LARGE.jpg")
        Dim CloneBitmap As New Bitmap(OrignalBitmap)
        OrignalBitmap.Dispose()
```

Which works like a charm. Now I have all the images in place and I can still access them as a file without anything locking. It works so well for what I need that I was thinking if its possible to do this for file formats other than images such as Csv files which are then used in a datagridview as a bound table?

Comment: If its unclear then I'll be more direct. Is there a way to copy a text file use the copy for futher processing in my application and dispose (not delete) the original text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is enough to open a File like this, so that it will not block other programs to access and open it.

```
Dim path1 As String = "C:\temp\temp.csv"
Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(path1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
  ' Do something with filestream
End Using
```

this will prevent even huge files to open without blocking access
you should check https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I thought to check that all the writing procedures also closed the file afterwoulds, which they did. Eventually i found what was causing the problem which was a missing column in the CSV file which was expected by my datagridview and causing it to keep the file open. fixed the issue by adding the missing column to the write procedure..